# Which characters shouldn't be used in a filename?

Tags: java, naming

I wrote a program which creates a file with the name derived from a users txtarea.
But it got me thinking ,what if the user uses whitespaces in his name or any other special symbols, which in turn than becomes a file with this name.

Can stuff go wrong?

Ifso,which signs/symbols should I allow to be used in a file's name?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, what symbols are allowed will depend on the local filesystem/OS. However, Java will check for you whether the filename is valid and throw an IOException if it isn't, when you try to create the file via `createNewFile()` for example. So stuff either won't go wrong or you'll be presented with an exception which you should handle.

See the Wikipedia page on [filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Filename_extensions) for more details on what's allowed and what's not in different OS/filesystems.

Comment: Also note that what characters are legal in filenames, and what characters are normally _wise_ in filenames, are two different questions. Windows filesystems, for example, permit many filenames that would be difficult-to-impossible to type from the command line. If you break the (simpler) command-line filename rules without a Very Good Reason, your users are likely to try to strangle you.